# Display legend and colorAxis at different positions in Highchart

Tags: javascript, highcharts, heatmap

I want to display [legend](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend) for a line series at the top and [colorAxis](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/colorAxis) for heatmap at the right side in a chart. There is a global option to position the legend but no separate option for each series.

Highcharts Version: v4.3.1

Answer (score 2):

That feature is not yet implemented in Highcharts core, but it should be available soon: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/11309

For now you can move `colorAxis` from the legend to another place on the chart in this way:

```
(function(H) {
    H.wrap(H.ColorAxis.prototype, 'drawLegendSymbol', function(proceed) {
        proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));

        this.legendItemWidth = 0;
        this.legendItemHeight = 0;
    });
}(Highcharts));

Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        marginRight: 80,
        events: {
            load: function() {
                var chart = this,
                    colorAxis = chart.colorAxis[0].axisParent.element,
                    mainSVG = chart.container.children[0],
                    xPos = chart.plotLeft + chart.plotWidth + 10,
                    yPos = chart.plotTop;

                mainSVG.appendChild(colorAxis);

                colorAxis.setAttribute(
                    'transform', 'translate(' + xPos + ', ' + yPos + ')'
                )
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        ...,
        showInLegend: true
    }, {
        ...,
        showInLegend: true
    }],
    colorAxis: {
        layout: 'vertical'
    }
});
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0c9fkvwp/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts

Comment: This works well with the latest version. I'm using version v4.3.1. It does't have [colorAxis.layout](https://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/colorAxis.layout). colorAxis takes the same layout as legend. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Hi @Aamir Rizwan, Yes - you can overwrite a `horiz` property in the `init` method: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/qfgyp0mL/